# EF Core 7 - Class / Member Attributes

Tags: c#, .net-core, custom-attributes

I have a class attribute which defines a value, then I have a Method attribute, which even defines a value.
Then I want to access the value of the class attribute from the method attribute.

```
[MyClassAttribute("SomethingClass")]
public class MyClass 
{
    [MyMethodAttribute("SomethingMethod")]
    public void MyMethod() { }
}
```

Something like this should be done:

```
public class MyMethodAttribute : Attribute 
{
    public MyMethodAttribute(params string value) 
    {
        var myClassAttributeValue = PARENTCLASS.MyClassAttributeValue;
        var combined = myClassAttributeValue + value;
    }
}
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: I don't really understand. Since this is all compile time, why would you want to do it? If you explain what you're trying to achieve, maybe someone can offer a better solution to your problem? Otherwise, I can think of a couple of ways to do this with reflection, but it would be a pile of code I'm only willing to write if it'd really help you.

Comment: @JonKoeter I wann set something like a base role "ClassRoleName" on the class and then adding seperate method roles "MethodRole" for ApiController Methods. So the Attribute of the method should could combine the ClassRoleName + MethodRole name and then check if the "user" is allowed to access this method.

Comment: Then why not just pass the classname as the second parameter to your method attribute?